# Activities in Social Tab is not hidding in CRM 2016 using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I am following [this][1] blogpost to hide activities tab in social pan in Dynamics CRM but it throw following exception:

**Exception**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at HideSocialPaneItems (https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/
%7B636023406600001088%7D/WebResources/new_hidesocialitems?ver=1193008230:3:20)
    at eval (eval at RunHandlerInternal (https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1193008230:155:32), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at RunHandlerInternal (https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1193008230:155:1)
    at RunHandlers (https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1193008230:114:1)
    at OnScriptTagLoaded (https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1193008230:228:1)
    at https://dev16.abc.com/STICTESTDevOrg1/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1193008230:199:1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way of hiding tabs in the social pane: You can choose which one should be default, but unfortunately no do much more than that.